# Vue.js passing Boolean value to component attribute

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, parameter-passing

I want to create a simple input component in Vue, 
 which if the `IsPassword` condition was true, set its `type="password"` and if it is not, set it to `type="text"`.
*I'm probably making a mistake somewhere in the syntax because I'm getting `parsing javascript error`*

this is Simplified version of my code

**App.vue**

```
import InputText from "@/components/InputText.vue";

<template>
Username : <InputText/>
Password : <InputText :isPassword="true">
</template>
```

**InputText.vue**

```
<template>
<input :type="{IsPassword ? 'password':'text'}" value="Im getting error here"> 
</template>
<script>
export default {
    props: {
        IsPassword: Boolean
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should set the condition in curly brackets.

Second, the ternary operator syntax should look like `condition ? if condition true : if condition false`

So, it should look like

```html
<input :type="IsPassword ? 'password' : 'text'" value="Im getting error here">
```

Answer (score 1):

You will probably require to support feature types for the Input Text.

My suggestion is to keep logic outside templates:

```html
import InputText from "@/components/InputText.vue";

<template>
Username : <InputText/>
Password : <InputText is-password>
</template>
```

```html
<template>
   <input :type="inputType" > 
</template>

<script>
import {computed} from 'vue';

export default {
    props: {
        IsPassword: Boolean
    },
    setup(props){
       const inputType = computed(() => props.IsPassword ? 'password' : 'text')

      return{
         inputType
      }
    }

}
</script>
```